# Android: admob Ads contain Malicious Virus Alert - by cmsecurity

Tags: java, android, android-activity, admob, google-play-services

In my app, just using Google's Admob code for showing ads. But when it installs in my phone cm security shows following error and uninstall alert

```
Contains Malicious Ads (AdWare/Android.Admob.a[ads.gen])
Maliciois behavior:
Frequently spams pop-up ads
Forces user to tap on them
```

codes used to show ads

> import

```
 compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:9.2.0'
```

> in activity

```
 mAdView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
            .addTestDevice("9D34764KC29BED159B7BBCD1DA8F94DB")
            .build();
    mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
```

How to remove this alert?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can block that Ads..

Login with Admob account after that select your app and go to allow and block ads then after Select your category to filter ads.

In filter disable/block "your device is infected" ads.
its regular banner ads.

Comment: how to find-out  "your device is infected" ad network urls